# C structure assignment uses memcpy

Tags: c, data-structures, variable-assignment, memcpy

I have this `StructType st = StructTypeSecondInstance->st;` and it generates a segfault. The strange part is when the stack backtrace shows me:

```
0x1067d2cc: memcpy + 0x10 (0, 10000, 1, 1097a69c, 11db0720, bfe821c0) + 310
0x103cfddc: some_function + 0x60 (0, bfe823d8, bfe82418, 10b09b10, 0, 0) +
```

So, does struct assigment use `memcpy`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can't tell. Small structs may even be kept in registers. Whether `memcpy` is used is an implementation detail (it's not even *implementation-defined*, or *unspecified* -- it's just something the compiler writer choses and does not need to document.)

From a C Standard point of view, all that matters is that after the assigment, the struct members of the destination struct compare equal to the corresponding members of the source struct.

I would expect compiler writers to make a tradeoff between speed and simplicity, probably based on the size of the struct, the larger the more likely to use a `memcpy`. Some `memcpy` implementations are very sophisticated and use different algorithms depending on whether the length is some power of 2 or not, or the alignment of the src and dst pointers. Why reinvent the wheel or blow up the code with an inline version of `memcpy`?

Comment: >it's just something the compiler writer choses and does not need to document
I beleive that good ABI specify this issue. But not sure)

Comment: this is a bit strange to me because it seems to rely on the standard C library, while you might not have one if cross compiling for an embedded system for example. was this compiled with optimization?

Comment: @Gir: if you're cross-compiling for an embedded system without a standard library, you tell the compiler that via flags, and then it doesn't emit those libcalls.

Comment: @ThomasMore There just is no ABI for "How to copy a struct" adressed to compiler writers.

Comment: @ThomasMore: I have read many ABI documents (and helped to write one); I've never seen one define how C language assignment is performed.

Comment: @Jens yes, it seems I confused "where pass a struct" and "how to copy a struct"

Answer (score 2):

It might, yes.

This shouldn't be surprising: the struct assignment needs to copy a bunch of bytes from one place to another as quickly as possible, which happens to be the exact thing `memcpy()` is supposed to be good at. Generating a call to it seems like a no-brainer if you're a compiler writer.

Note that this means that assigning structs with lots of padding might be less efficient than optimally, since `memcpy()` can't skip the padding.

Comment: Ok, so what the assignment operator it's just syntactic sugar for memcpy ?

Comment: @coredump you can copy 32- and 64-bit objects using asm instructions. So the answer is rather no, then yes

Comment: @coredump: no, the assignment operator is the assignment operator.  The standard doesn't say anything about how the compiler should actually effect the assignment, so it is free to choose whatever it thinks is fastest.  It could copy byte-by-byte, it could copy each field with a natural copy for its type, it could use an inlined memcpy implementation, it could call memcpy, ...

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't say anything at all about how assignment (or any other operator) is actually realized by the compiler.  There's nothing stopping a compiler from (say) generating a function call for every operation in your source file.

The compiler has license to implement assignment as it thinks best.  Most of the time, with most compilers on most platforms, this means that if the structure is reasonably small, the compiler will generate an inline sequence of move instructions; if the structure is large, calling memcpy is common.

It would be perfectly valid, however, for the compiler to loop over generating random bitfields and stop when one of them matches the source of the assignment (Let's call this algorithm *bogocopy*).

Compilers that support non-hosted operation usually give you a switch to turn off emitting such libcalls if you're targeting a platform without an available (or complete) libc.

Comment: As an extremely minor note, `*p = *p;` is sometimes valid, but `memcpy(p, p, sizeof(t));` never is (contrasting C99's 6.5.16.1:3 and 7.21.2.1). The compiler may come with a `memcpy()` that works with exactly self-overlapping arguments, but when it replaces a struct assignment with a `memcpy()`, it does not just assume that a `memcpy()` function is there, it assumes that you are using **its** function that handles `memcpy(p, p, sizeof(t));`. A random `memcpy()` function does not have to.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler and platform. Assignment of big objects can use `memcpy`. But it must not be the reason of segfault.

Comment: Yes, most certainly not, but I was surprised to see a call to memcpy.